# How to handle aggregates relationship in Event Sourcing properly?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, rdbms, cqrs, event-sourcing

When having a somehow "complex" domain model, it's unavoidable to have related entities (that's the sense of aggregate root). But how should I reconstitute relationships from events? Searching by other aggregate id in serialized events is obviously not an option.

I have an idea to use such DB structure (for example). It has aggregates tables with just id and foreign keys, to simplify retrieving all necessary events from different entities. Doesn't this break the ES principles?

[image]

Comment: What is "the ES principle"?

Comment: Storing only events in write model?

Comment: I think you have them all mixed up. In ES all events are stored in an `Event store`. Then the `Aggregates` a.k.a. the `Write Models` are reconstructed from there before they can execute commands and generate more events that are appended to the `Event store` and so on. Your table schemas are kind of confusing.

Comment: That's exactly how I did understand that. I just want to have an opportunity to load related aggregates, i.e. all shops created by given user

Comment: Or Order aggregate with `addItem(Product p)` method, which creates OrderItem model which contains relation between order and product and stores data about current prices (in case they change), because that makes sense in rich domain model. So it should launch plenty of events for 3 entities - OrderItemCreated, ProductAttachedToOrderItem, OrderItemAttachedToOrder, etc, etc. But events in aggregate should be related only to that aggregate... ES looks clear on simple examples from articles and books, but when it comes to applying it on practice, my mind just blows

Comment: Oh I understand now. You load aggregates only to send commands to them, not to "read" them, so to be clear. What you want is something else. You want to load related **projections** of those aggregates. You do this by creating&maintaining a `Read model`, i.e. a list of all orders by user, implemented by a sql table, builded by listening to the relevant events.

Comment: That `read model` is updated only when new events are raised. It probably have indexes for OrderId (primary key) and userId in order for the query to be fast. It also could contain the userName, so you don't have to use joins either. Read models contain everything you need for a particulary View. Other Views could use other Read models. Read models coukd be many and related,i.e. you could have a read model that is a list of all shipped orders. Other one could be a list of all unshipped orders and so on. The idea is that read models myst be very fast and use no `joins` when you query them.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But I can't understand the thing - DDD says that "rich domain model" consists from entities which handles business logic, and we work with them as they model the domain objects. So I can imagine i.e. `order.addItem(product)` method, where OrderItem creating and making relationship with Order and Product. But in ES we should rise events for all these entities, which can't be done in Order model. So I should just throw away "rich domain model" idea? Or this is what "sagas" in ES are for?

Comment: That is a good idea, keep it. Rich means with behavior and Aggregate have behavior. But in almost any DDD online shop you may not call `order.addItem (product)` but `order.addItem(productType, productId,productPrice,quatity )` because both are Aggregates!

Comment: But aren't aggregate roots and aggregates different things? Aggregate root can contain different aggregates and have some business logic to operate them. So OrderItem is aggregate, Order is aggregate root. Isn't it? Or this can't be applied for ES?

Comment: That feel when understanding each part of concept, but stuck for days putting them together in practical application...

Comment: No, `aggregate roots` cannot contain other `aggregates`. An `aggregate` contains **exactly one** `aggregate root` (that is of type entity) and **optionally** other nested/sub entities. An `aggregate` is like a folder/directory and an aggregate root is like an 'index.html' file; other nested entities are like files inside that aggregate folder, that cannot be accessed by the outside world. All links from other `aggregates` would point only to `aggregate-folder/index.html` . This is important to understand. Nested/sub entities cannot be referenced, not even by ID by other aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for some material for thoughts.

Comment: Are you ready to combine these comments into a proper answer?

Comment: After I'll try and figure it out finally

Comment: Does projections and projectors belongs to Domain layer? (or Application or Presentation?)

Comment: Domain layer, but in the Read side.

Comment: Classic of genre: http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/22/4-secrets-inter-aggregate-communication-event-sourced-system/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> DDD says that "rich domain model" consists from entities which handles business logic, and we work with them as they model the domain objects

Yes, and that's still true when you use event sourcing.

> So I can imagine i.e. order.addItem(product) method, where OrderItem creating and making relationship with Order and Product.

Aha, no -- not in either approach.  If Order and Product are different aggregates, then `order.addItem(product)` is not a spelling that you would use.  The order and the product don't share responsibility for the product's state.  Or, put another way, we never nest aggregates roots inside each other.

The usual spelling, per the rules of DDD, would be `order.addItem(product.id)`.  Note this important difference: changing an Order cannot change any of the details of a Product.

It's part of the point: each bit of state in your domain has a single authority responsible for maintaining its consistency.

Note: the spelling `order.addItem(product)` makes sense for a model where Product is an entity that is not an aggregate root, but instead is subordinate to Order (and more precisely, each Product is associated with exactly one order).

> But if Item has many-to-one relationship to Order, shouldn't it contain orderId instead? (Not Order containing list of ItemId). But that would mean it should be Item.AddToOrder(order.Id), which makes not so much sense.

The short answer is that you get different spellings for the methods depending on how you decide to model the data, and which items are responsible for maintaining the integrity of aggregates.

Working backwards - part of the motivation for aggregates at all (rather than just having one large consistency boundary around your entire model) is the idea of concurrent modification of different parts of the model.  Whether or not OrderItem is a separate aggregate from Order is going to depend -- in part -- on how important it is that two different OrderItems can be modified concurrently.

For cases like online shopping carts, that's probably not super important.

For a setting where many parties are trying to modify the same order at the same time, something like

```
OrderItem.create(order.id, product.id)
```

Wouldn't be unreasonable.

> And still, aggregate root contains other aggregates, and OrderItem in that case is aggregate, not aggregate root or value object.

An aggregate root has responsibility for one aggregate.  That aggregate (which fundamentally is just "state") can conceptually be the current state of multiple entities subordinate to the root, each managing a specific part of the whole.

> And if I'm right, aggregate root contains business logic to control inner aggregates, so we still need to build aggregate root which contains other entities in it.

"Inner aggregate" doesn't make sense -- aggregates don't nest.  *Entities* nest, with the outermost entity playing the role of the aggregate root.

So, how do we build nested entities?

Let's step back, and look at how we typically create a single entity.  We run some query (like getById) to get the *State* that we had previously saved.

```
Factory {
    Entity fromState(currentState) {
        return new (entity);
    }

    State fromEntity(theEntity) {
        return theEntity.getState();
    }
}
```

Nested entities work the same way, with the subordinate entities taking over part of the work.  For an Order, it might look like...

```
Factory {
    Order fromState(currentState) {
        List<OrderItem> items = ...

        for (State.Item itemState : currentState.items()) {
            OrderItem orderItem = OrderItem.from(itemState)
            items.add(orderItem)
        }

        return new Order(items);
    }
}

Order {
    State getState() {
        State currentState = State.EMPTY;

        for(OrderItem orderItem : this.items) {
            currentState = currentState.addItemState(orderItem.getState())

        return currentState
    }
}
```

When we use *event sourcing*, the bit that changes is that we use collections of events instead of state.

```
Factory {
    Order fromEvents(history) {

        // The one tricky bit -- the history we will be looking
        // at is a mix of histories from all of the entities that
        // coordinate the changes to the aggregate, so we may need
        // to untangle that.

        Map<OrderItemId, Events> = itemHistories
        for (Event e : history )
            items.put(e.orderItemId, e)

        List<OrderItem> items = ...

        for (Events events: itemHistories.values) {
            OrderItem orderItem = OrderItem.from(events)
            items.add(orderItem)
        }
        return new Order(items);
    }
}

Order {
    List<Event> getEvents () {
        List<Event> events = new List();

        for(OrderItem orderItem : this.items) {
            events.addAll(orderItem.getEvents())
        }
        return events
    }
}
```

Comment: But if Item has many-to-one relationship to Order, shouldn't it contain orderId instead? (Not Order containing list of ItemId). But that would mean it should be Item.AddToOrder(order.Id), which makes not so much sense. Or I'm still "thinking in RDBMS"?

Comment: And still, aggregate root contains other aggregates, and OrderItem in that case is aggregate, not aggregate root or value object. (Ok, it's more like VO in that case, but what if its aggregate, like User <- Shop in my DB schema). And if I'm right, aggregate root contains business logic to control inner aggregates, so we still need to build aggregate root which contains other entities in it.

Answer (score 2):

You take care of any relationships with keys but they are not enforced by anything like foreign key constraints like in a DB. In fact the key of a user in your shop event may be a human readable ID. There is no requirement to link via the Guids.

Mapping from one to the other is done in projections that help you make correct information displayed and the proper fields in your commands.